# How do I find out which plugin is exceeding memory limits?

Tags: plugins, memory

I had an issue today when my sites had stopped working. Calling up the link just showed a cryptic message `Database connection error`, on all my sites on one server. The error disappeared on rebooting.

While trying to get to the root of the issue, I was examining syslog (I'm using Debian 7), and found the following entries:

```
Jun 15 05:46:03 myserver suhosin[8368]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/mylocation/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:46:21 myserver suhosin[8372]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/mylocation/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:46:38 myserver suhosin[8368]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/mylocation/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:46:54 myserver suhosin[8376]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/mylocation/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:55:01 myserver /USR/SBIN/CRON[8508]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 15 05:56:59 myserver suhosin[8514]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/kgimoa.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:57:18 myserver suhosin[8516]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/kgimoa.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
Jun 15 05:57:33 myserver suhosin[8514]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker 'myipx.y.z.a', file '/var/www/virtual/joel.co.in/kgimoa.com/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfUtils.php', line 502)
```

The error repeats itself.

Looking at the code, on line 502:

```
 public static function iniSet($key, $val){
                if(self::funcEnabled('ini_set')){
                        @ini_set($key, $val);
                }
        }
```

Is this because one of my plugins/theme is using an excess amount of RAM? How can I isolate and identify which one? Other than disabling each plugin one by one and waiting for the error to show up in syslog, is there a quicker, and directed method?

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't say that the plugin is using a lot of RAM. It says that the plugin tried to raise the memory_limit to 256M. These are two different things.

A plugin, or even the core code, trying to adjust the memory limit up very high is fairly normal, if it thinks that it might be doing something that will use a lot of RAM. WordPress does it when doing image processing, for example, because large images need lots of memory to work with, temporarily.

In this case, it appears that the Wordfence plugin has a line in it somewhere that calls that iniSet function to try to raise the memory_limit. That's it. Doesn't say that it has actually used any of it, and setting a higher limit is not particularly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

The message itself comes from [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) - part of the "hardened PHP project" - which gives you this error log messages. Nothing to really worry about, as it's not the amount of memory that the script is nagging about, but only the fact that the plugin *tried to* raise the limit. You could try telling your host to deactivate those messages for you, or - if you have those abilities - [configure](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html) it yourself.